# IntentReceiverLeaked using AdMob

Tags: java, android, android-intent, admob

For some reason I keep hitting this error when trying to use AdMob in my app (meditation network).

```
Activity com.tfl.tfl.tagDetailActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.adsdk.sdk.banner.AdView$6@405940a0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.tfl.tfl.tagDetailActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.adsdk.sdk.banner.AdView$6@405940a0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

Here are the pieces of code relevant:
OnCreate

```
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tag_detail_ad_layout);
    layout.addView(adView);
    adView.loadAd(buildAdMobRequest());
```

...

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

By reading around it seems destroying the adview should fix the problem but I am still getting the error. The error arises when I tap 'back' from the page which contains the ads.

Comment: So the AdMob AdView is com.google.ads.AdView.  com.adsdk.sdk.banner.AdView must be an AdView of one of the networks you're mediating with.  Perhaps their SDK or adapter has an issue.  Which networks are you mediating with?

Comment: I only have one other network: MobFox. The full error log actually mentions MobFox in it. For conciseness I didn't include in original post but you can see it here: http://pastebin.com/pkiGiDPd  Assuming the adapter has an issue, is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: One thing to note is that I am using the 4.0 RTM version of the MobFox SDK (Someone from MobFox previously reached out to be and suggested I use it).

Comment: @Zaheer, did you ever resolve this?  I have the exact same issue with Mobfox and Admob!! :-(

Comment: @Zippy Unfortunately this was a while ago and don't exactly remember :/ I might've just given up tbh.